# pause\ play the video

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have main() and thread which transmitting video.

is possible to use the function

```
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

from the main?
the pipeline is in the thread (with all the video code).

when I tried it, it actually paused the pipeline, but I also got this error:

```
status: pause
Bus error (core dumped)
```

and it throw me out of the program.

if someone know what to do it will be great!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that. And if you get a crash, simply fire up gdb and get a backtrace:

```
gdb ./my-app
run
# when it crashes
bt
```